# Is it possible to get Sheets to recognize my REGEXEXTRACT results as a date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column filled with date data in the following format: `[Date: 09-Nov-2020 10:29 AM]`

I've used the following formula to take out only the date info:
`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,".*: (.*)\S\D"))` (where `C2:C` is the column with the unformatted dates).

This gets the dates to display as `09-Nov-2020`, but this doesn't seem to be recognized by Google Sheets as a date. When I try to edit the number formatting, nothing changes.

Oddly, I have a Data Validation list based on these shortened dates, and when I change the number formatting there it updates properly.

I'm trying to set it up so I can use a MATCH formula to locate the date based on this `DD-Mmm-YYYY` format, but since Sheets doesn't see the result of the `REGEXEXTRACT` as a date, I can't find a formula that works to do that (including `MATCH`, `FILTER`, etc.)

Unfortunately I can't directly share the sheet because of sensitive information stored on it, but based on the formula above is there something else I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula:

```
=value(Text(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,".*: (.*)\S")),"dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was almost perfect but got me the solution. I just had to move the ```ArrayFormula``` to the beginning and that got it to work. Final working formula is ```=ArrayFormula(value(Text((REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,".*: (.*)\S)),"dd-mmm-yyyy"))```

Answer (score 1):

While the formula [provided by Rocky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64773277) can be used to retrieve the day part of the date, it doesn't keep the `time`: `09-Nov-2020 10:29 AM` becomes `09-Nov-2020 00:00 AM`.

That's because [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) is used to format to `dd-mmm-yyyy`, which doesn't contain the `time` part.

There's no need to use `TEXT`, though, and [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en) can be used directly to transform the string returned by `REGEXEXTRACT` to a date:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,".*: (.*)\S"))))
```

[image]

#### Note:

- [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) is used here to ignore the empty cells in `C`.

#### Reference:

- [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en)